# Set default value for datetime for entire database

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to find a way that I can change the default value for `datetime` columns for all tables in SQL Server. Currently any new columns of type `datetime` that don't allow `nulls` have a default of `1901/01/01 00:00:00`. I would like to change this value to `0001/01/01 00:00:00` to match the default `DateTime` value in Visual Studio.

I know I can do this on a column by column basis through the interface or by using:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable DEFAULT 'SOMEDATE' FOR YourColumn
```

But this is done *after* table creation and is a nuisance to maintain in production. I am trying to find a way to set it so any *new* tables would 'inherit' this from some higher level, I'm assuming the database settings.

Something like:

```
 ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET DEFAULT 'SOMEDATE' FOR TYPE DATETIME
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This will help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211352/changing-the-use-of-getdate-in-the-entire-database.

Comment: There's no DB-wide setting that you can tweak - default constraints are always on a **per column** basis.

Comment: For people down voting this, can you please state why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it globally using a single command.

One suggestion is to create a user defined data type from `DATETIME2` like following.

**1- Create Default** You need to first create a Default type like following.

```
CREATE DEFAULT Default_DT
AS '0001/01/01 00:00:00'
```

**2- Create User Defined DataType** Once the default is created you need to create your Custom Data Type from `DATETIME2` like following.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DateTimeD] FROM [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
```

**3- Bind Default** You need to map the Default type to your user defined data type like following.

```
EXEC sys.sp_bindefault @defname=N'[dbo].[Default_DT]', @objname=N'[dbo].[DateTimeD]'
```

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(DtColumn [DateTimeD], ID INT);
insert into TEST(id) select 1
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

**Output:**

```
DtColumn                         ID
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000       1
```

Comment: I'm working on SQL Server 2019 but above insert failed since it is looking for a value for not null column.

Comment: It will happen only when the default is not mapped to the user defined data type. You can use the SSMS to attach the default type

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I directly executed your script. Maybe better you can add following command too: EXEC sys.sp_bindefault @defname=N'[dbo].[Default_DT]', @objname=N'[dbo].[DateTimeD]'

Comment: @Eralper, thanks, I have updated the binding in the answer.

Comment: The above code only work on SQL Server 2008 or higher version of SQL Server.

Comment: This looks like it will suit my purposes! Thanks a lot.